# Node JS ./configure + make fails unable to remap python lib-dynload/itertools.dll to same address as parent

Tags: node.js, cygwin

This might be more of a CYGWIN question than a Nodejs but here goes.

I installed Cygwin yesterday and on the packages selection I just clicked next as it looked like most were pre-selected, and then today read this guide http://boxysystems.com/index.php/step-by-step-instructions-to-install-nodejs-on-windows/ on installing nodejs.

The ./configure had an error that it was unable to remap python lib-dynload/itertools.dll to same address as parent. As the process still completed I tried the make command, but it fails on the same error.

So, I opened cygwin setup.exe and this time I clicked the source checkbox for all the Python packages. But still get the same error. Should I now go to Cygwin and check all the source packages for the Make packages, delete it and reinstall from scratch using the above guide. Or something else?

Any help gratefull received/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the official 0.5.x windows build from http://nodejs.org/#download - you just have to download a .exe file and you can start it.

Comment: I did this, I click the exe, it opens a terminal window, but any command I enter it just puts three dots below for more commands

Comment: Uhm, yes, you're in a javascript shell now. Try "1+1" or some other valid JS expression. To launch a node script file, use the windows cmd shell and run `path\to\node scriptname` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Versions 0.5.X have problems with Cygwin and because of developing clean Windows version Cygwin environment is now unsupported. Stable version 0.4.12 builds on Cygwin with no problems. If you want to use node.js unstable 0.5.X branch on Windows use windows build at official node.js site.

check this out:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows)
Update Sept 1, 2011 -- as of today, v0.5.5 does not build on Cygwin (errors on make). Use v.0.5.4 (ie. follow instructions below and use "git checkout v0.5.4".

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/API-changes-between-v0.4-and-v0.6
Cygwin build is no longer supported. Use native windows builds instead.